# Why .lastPathComponent from file picker returns weird file name?

Tags: ios, swift, file

I'm trying to get real file name from file picker. I used two ways, such:

```
let fileName = file.lastPathComponent
```

and such:

```
let fileName = FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: file.absoluteString)
```

where `file` is `let file = urls[0]`. In any time I received strange letters set:

```
%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.rtf
```

the real file name is: `Без названия.rtf`. The real file name is on Russian language , when I tried to get file with file name on English, everything was OK, so as I see all problems are connected with Russian file names. Maybe someone faced with similar problems and knows how to solve them? I also tried utf-8 encoding but it didn't help me :(

### UPDATE

I send it to a chat server via websocket task:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, 

    didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            
            let file = urls[0]
            do{
                let fileData = try Data.init(contentsOf: file)
                let encodedString = String.init(data: fileData, encoding: .isoLatin1)!
                
                let fileName = FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: file.path)
                let time = Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
                
                
                print(encodedString.count)
                wsSendString(message: ChatMStrings.init().sendFilePart(fileContent: encodedString, fileName: fileName, fileSize: encodedString.count))
                
            }catch{
                print("contents could not be loaded")
            }
        }
```

sending object:

```
func sendFilePart(fileContent: String, fileName: String, fileSize: Int) -> String {
        
        let sendFile:[String:[String:Any]] = ["chat":["a":"send_file",
                                                      "body":fileContent,
                                                      "filename":fileName,
                                                      "total":fileSize]]
        
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: sendFile, options: [])
        return String(data: jsonData!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)!
    }
```

sending method:

```
func wsSendString(message:String) {
        self.webSocket!.send(URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(message)) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("WebSocket sending error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        
        
        self.listenWS()
    }
```

websocket creation:

```
 webSocket = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: request)
webSocket!.resume()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222904/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-why-lastpathcomponent-from-file-picker-returns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue there is that you are using the wrong URL property. file.absoluteString is wrong. you should use file.path.

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "Без названия.rtf")
print(fileURL) // %D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.rtf -- file:///private/var/folders/00/l311vw5s2550g5gz2h25b2vr0000gp/T/
print(fileURL.path)  // /private/var/folders/00/l311vw5s2550g5gz2h25b2vr0000gp/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.MyPlayground-comparable-enumeration-AD2BDA8A-BF7B-4F92-B561-B080E72B4DF0/Без названия.rtf
print(fileURL.absoluteString)  // file:///private/var/folders/00/l311vw5s2550g5gz2h25b2vr0000gp/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.MyPlayground-comparable-enumeration-AD2BDA8A-BF7B-4F92-B561-B080E72B4DF0/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.rtf
let fileNamePath = FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: fileURL.path)
print(fileNamePath) // "Без названия.rtf\n"
let fileNameAbsoluteString = FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString)
print(fileNameAbsoluteString)  // %D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.rtf
```